# Iterate a List of object inside a Map angular4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

```
export class Person{
name:string,
age:number,
listAdress:Map<string,Adresses[]>

}
```

I need to parse all adresses of each person

```
    <div *ngFor="let person of persons">
<div *ngFor="let adr of person.listAdress">==> it is possible ??
</div>
```

how can I iterate all adresses with key of Map

if we suppose that the key of Map is 'Fes'

Comment: Where are you stuck? Also why not just make it an array?

Comment: I can't show adr object of the second iteration

Answer (score 0):

The [`Map` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) exposes a [`values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) method which you can use to get the `Address[]`.

The data structure is a bit confusing, but I'll show you how you can get the first array of `Address` from the person and iterate over that with `*ngFor`. ([`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) requires an Array-like structure, not just any iterable).

Create a method in your component class to convert the `values` iterable into an array:

*In component class:*

```
getAddresses(person: Person): Address[] {
  return Array.from(person.listAddress.values())[0];
}
```

*In template:*

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons">
  <div *ngFor="let adr of getAddresses(person)"></div>
</div>
```

You can also use the `forEach()` method to iterate over each value and add it to another array (again in a separate method):

*In component class:*

```
getAllAddresses(person: Person): Address[] {
  const allAddresses: Address[] = [];
  person.listAddress.forEach((value: Address[]) => {
    allAddresses.push(...value);
  });
  return allAddresses;
}
```

*In template:*

```
<ul> All Addresses: 
  <li *ngFor="let adr of getAllAddresses(person)">
    {{ adr.num + ' ' + adr.street }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a link to a working app with both examples: https://stackblitz.com/edit/address-map

Comment: I got this exception ::
 =>>>>>ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '[object Map Iterator]'. Current value: '[object Map Iterator]'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:9801)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:9779)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:9948)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:14002)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:13976)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:14805)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14707)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] ck @ zone.js:1573

Comment: Apologies, I was wrong the first time around. Updated my answer with working code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot loop on a `Map` with `ngFOr` as it's not considered as `Iterable`.

To do that, you might first apply a transformation thanks to `Array.from` or manually looping on them as pointed out by [@vincecampanale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5932590/vincecampanale) BUT it'll hurt your your performances as it'll be triggered and run on every change detection.

If it's a small app, fine.
If you care about perfs, you should rather use a (pure!) pipe to apply the transformation to the Map + `trackBy` on the `ngFor`.

For the pipe, no need to do it yourself, you can use [ngx-pipes](https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes) and do

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons">
  <div *ngFor="let adr of person.listAdress | values"></div>
</div>
```

It be better for perfs and avoid coding something that does not exists. Also add a trackBy and it'll be excellent :)